# How to Solve the Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects Error?

Tags: python

Everyone Please help me in how to solve this error, I am trying all that i can also get he help from many wbsite but not success to solve this.

```
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an error you get using Python 3.12.

As of February the 1st 2024, [multidict](https://pypi.org/project/multidict) released a wheel for Python 3.12.

You can [download it here](https://pypi.org/project/multidict/#files), but it will also be updated over the coming days in the affected libraries. `aiohttp` as an example updated theirs today (02-02-2024).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I forgot to ask at that time.